# How/Where to efficiently perform startup tasks in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

When the application starts/begins I want to perform initialisation tasks such as get groups data from the database. I have already done this in one of my controller in the controller initialize method:

```
SqlActions sa = new SqlActions();
DataTable dt = sa.ExeSP("getdata");

//using the datatable I then fill IEnumerable lists for my controller actions.
```

My question is: I have seven controllers and I do not want to replicate the above 7 times because the data is the same throughout the controllers. Where can I place the above code once which is then available to all controllers ???

Answer (score 0):

Consider using WebActivator:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebActivator/

> WebActivator is a NuGet package that allows other packages to easily
>   bring in Startup and Shutdown code into a web application. This gives
>   a much cleaner solution than having to modify global.asax with the
>   startup logic from many packages.

Usage:

```
using System;

[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(
    typeof(MyNamespace.MyInitializator), "PreStart")]

namespace MyNamespace {
    public static class MyInitializator {
        public static void PreStart() {
            // Add your start logic here
        }
    }
}
```

You can populate a common static cache with your data and use it in all your controllers.

Comment: Thanks Jakub for your reply, so for example I want to share "IEnumerable<classB> list" between all my controllers - how will I achieve this with what you have mentioned??

Comment: Just create a static class `classBCache` with `static IEnumerable<classB>` list inside. And read about caching in general.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't distributing a component that must run its own initialization in whatever project it's dropped in, keep it simple and use Application_Start. See your current global.asax and how it calls methods on classes in your App_Start folder. It's a bit cleaner this way IMHO and keeps with the current convention for other startup code in your project.